# SQL query item name from and ID

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database with the following structure and need some help running a query.

Table 1 is:

Order ID :  Order Date

Table 2 is:

Order ID: Item ID: Item Name

I need a query that will return a count of orders, grouped by the Item name in a specific orderdate.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Have you tried any code yourself? If no, try it. If yes, show us some of your code.

Answer (score -1):

select count(*) from table2 inner join table1 on table2.orderid = table1.orderid where table1.orderdate="some date" and itemname="sepcific name"